# FBAudienceNetwork for iOS Static or Dynamic?

Tags: ios, facebook, admob

I use Facebook for iOS with Admob Mediation. The Admob Manual offers 
"Download the latest version of the Facebook Audience Network SDK for iOS and link FBAudienceNetwork.framework in your project."
I downloaded FBAudienceNetwork-5.5.0 and see two paths "Dynamic" and "Static". oth of these folders contain FBAudienceNetwork.framework. 
What is their difference? No readme in archive. No readme in archive.  I tried to search but can not find.